# Labels inside pie chart (highcharts) without the distance trick

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I would like to display some labels directly inside the pie chart, inside the slices. The problem is, I'm already using the data labels for different values and I need to add labels inside the chart (and possibly elsewhere) in addition to the existing data labels. What would be the best way to approach this, since the label distance trick is not going to work?

Also perhaps related to this, I was experimenting with renderer but the text rendered this way is underneath the chart.

I appreciate any response in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [annotations module](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/annotations-module) which allows you to define labels attached to certain points.

You can control the distance from the point by a couple of options such as:

- [align](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/annotations.labelOptions.align) - left, center, right
- [verticalAlign](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/annotations.labelOptions.verticalAlign) - top, middle, bottom
- [x](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/annotations.labelOptions.x) - a number
- [y](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/annotations.labelOptions.y) - a number
- [distance](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/annotations.labelOptions.distance) - a positive number

For centering labels in pie slices, set `x` and `y` to zero.

```
const data = [10, 50, 50, 20]

Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    type: 'pie'
  },

  series: [{
    keys: ['y', 'id'],
    data: data.map((v, i) => ([v, String(i)]))
  }],

  annotations: [{
    labels: data.map((v, i) => ({
      point: String(i),
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    }))
  }]
});
```

live example: http://jsfiddle.net/ndopca3p/

output:

[image: pie annotations]

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for the delay. I tried your solution but the annotations just won't render this way. I suspect this might have something to do with angular2. In the meantime I implemented a different solution where I place the labels manually. I am going to accept your answer because it works within the scope of this question.